# What are the implications, if any, if Ἀλφαῖος and Κλωπᾶς are indeed the same individual?

Tags: john, onomastics

In John 19:25, it is written,

> <sup>25</sup> Now there stood by the cross of Jesus His mother, and His mother’s sister, Mary the wife of Clopas (Κλωπᾶ),<sup>1</sup> and Mary Magdalene. <sup>NKJV</sup>

<sup>ΚΕʹ</sup> εἱστήκεισαν δὲ παρὰ τῷ σταυρῷ τοῦ Ἰησοῦ ἡ μήτηρ αὐτοῦ καὶ ἡ ἀδελφὴ τῆς μητρὸς αὐτοῦ Μαρία ἡ τοῦ Κλωπᾶ καὶ Μαρία ἡ Μαγδαληνή <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

Regarding the proper name Κλωπᾶς, Joseph Henry Thayer (translating Wilke) wrote,<sup>2</sup>

[image: Thayer, p. 351, Κλωπᾶς]

Regarding the proper name Ἀλφαῖος, Joseph Henry Thayer (translating Wilke) wrote,<sup>3</sup>

[image: Thayer, p. 29, Ἀλφαῖος]

What are the implications, if any, if Ἀλφαῖος and Κλωπᾶς are indeed the same individual?

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Κλωπᾶ is the gentive declension of Κλωπᾶς.
<sup>2</sup> p. [351](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA351#v=onepage&q&f=false)
<sup>3</sup> p. [29](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false)

### References

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament: Being Grimm Wilke’s Clavis Novi Testamenti.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7wVNDAjFkRoC) Trans. Thayer, Joseph Henry. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald. Rev. ed. New York: American Book, 1889.

Wilke, Christian Gottlob. [*Clavis Novi Testamenti Philologica. Ed. Grimm, Carl Ludwig Wilibald.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HL8CAAAAQAAJ) Lipsiae: Libraria Arnoldiana, 1868.

Comment: This is a rather open ended question, but also not one that seems all that interesting. Surely the implication is that one of the disciple's mothers was a follower of Jesus and perhaps a friend and supporter of Mary?

Comment: There is a lengthy discussion of this topic in an appendix to _The Eastern Orthodox Bible: New Testament._  I can't take the time to craft a good answer, but the editor cites an article called [The Relatives of Jesus](https://biblicalstudies.org.uk/article_relatives_bauckham.html), by Richard Bauckham; an [article in the Catholic Encyclopedia](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/08280a.htm); and a [synaxarion entry](http://www.goarch.org/chapel/saints_view?contentid=254) at the website of the Greek Orthodox Archdiocese of America in his discussion.  Perhaps the material will be of interest